# Dismiss all UIAlertview from application in iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I want to remove all UIAlertview in my application when i enter to background mode. I am using the following code to do that.

```
for (UIWindow* w in [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows)
    for (NSObject *o in w.subviews)
    {
        if ([o isKindOfClass:[UIAlertView class]])
        {
            [(UIAlertView *)o dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:[(UIAlertView *)o cancelButtonIndex] animated:YES];
        }
    }
```

It is working properly in iOS6. When i run the same application in iOS7 device it is not working. Have any ideas?

Comment: How does it not work? What exactly happens? Does it make it into the `if statement`?

Comment: No it is not going into if statement even alert view is visible

Comment: In iOS7, `windows` does not contain the alert view windows. They are managed by another stack of windows which are not exposed.

Answer (score 2):

There is _UIAlertManager private class which has a method topMostAlert which returns top most alert. This works in iOS 7.0 also.

```
UIAlertView *topAlert = [NSClassFromString(@"_UIAlertManager") 
performSelector:@selector(topMostAlert)]
```

Comment: This is not safe for AppStore.

Answer (score 1):

Try This one

```
UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
for (UIView *view in w.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIAlertView class]]) {
        [(UIAlertView *)view dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:[(UIAlertView *)view cancelButtonIndex] animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is also not working. This code stopped working in iOS6 itself.

Comment: This doesn't detect the UIAlertView from the window's subviews.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this hope it will help you

```
    for (UIWindow* w in [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows) {
      for (NSObject *o in w.subviews) {
         for (NSObject *secnonO in o.subviews) {
          if ([secnonO isKindOfClass:[UIAlertView class]]) {
              [(UIAlertView *)o dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:[(UIAlertView *)o cancelButtonIndex] animated:YES];
           }
         }
       }
   }
```

Comment: There is no subviews property for NSObject class

Comment: This does not work on iOS7.

Comment: Is there any other ways to do this

Answer (score -1):

Use this recursive method

```
- (void)removeAlert:(NSArray *)subviews {
    for (UIView * subview in subviews){
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIAlertView class]]){
            [(UIAlertView *)subview dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:[(UIAlertView *)subview cancelButtonIndex] animated:NO];
        } else {
            [self removeAlert:subview.subviews];
        }
    }
}
```

Call it from applicationDidEnterBackground like this

```
[self removeAlert:application.windows];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't work on iOS7. `windows` does not contain the alert view windows.